# Android : How to load an activity faster when calling it from another activity, even while loading several contents in the second activity

Tags: java, android, oncreate

I'm new to java and android so I am asking these kind of questions here to understand how it should work.

I have 2 Activities in my app viz `Welcome_Activity.java` and `Content_Activity.java`

The First Activity work smoothly but the problem comes when the `Content_Activity(Second Activity)` is called from `Welcome_Activity(First Activity)`

In the `onCreate` of `Second Activity`, I think the contents which are too many cause the Activity to load too slow.

How to solve this issue?

Example :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_Puzzle_game);

    q1_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.q1_tv);
    q2_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.q2_tv);
    q3_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.q3_tv);
    q4_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.q4_tv);
    q5_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.q5_tv);
    q6_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.q6_tv);
    q7_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.q7_tv);
    q8_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.q8_tv);
    q9_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.q9_tv);
    q10_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.q10_tv);

    bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt1);
    bt2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt2);
    bt3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt3);
    bt4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt4);
    bt5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt5);
    bt6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt6);
    bt7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt7);
    bt8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt8);
    bt9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt9);
    bt10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt10);

    SP = getSharedPreferences("saved_data", MODE_PRIVATE);
    solved = SP.getInt("solved", 0);

    // LoadLevel & ResumeGame is just a method to get data from another class that have array Strings to fill the textviews and buttons 

    if (solved > 0) {
        ResumeGame(null);
    }
    else {
        LoadLevel(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: why is the content_activity slow? are you consuming a webservice or something?

Comment: Can you please explain what kind of data you are trying to load in your Content_Activity which causes slow loading?

Comment: Please share onCreate code

Comment: Can you provide code of `onCreate` for slow activity? What all you are trying to do over there?

Comment: Have you try to prepare require data in background thread instead of ui thread ?

Comment: By the way, You should look into a library like Butterknife to reduce your need to write findViewById

Comment: i edited my post added example to make my point clear please guy check it out

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assume you are fetching data in `ResumeGame` & `LoadGame` methods either from web services or from local app storage; if so try to do fetching thing in other than main thread (UI thread) and as soon as you get the data try to pass this data on UI thread. The best way to do it for you (beginner) use [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), usable callbacks in `AsyncTask` could be:

- `doInBackground`: here write your code to get the data
- `onPostExecute`: Here you can fill your UI views like button label, text of `TextView`

I hope this will help you in order to improve performance.

Comment: it's just a class named "questions" with strings array for each level .. so i'm loading data from a class i just pick 10 elements from the array that inside that class

Comment: If you are not using any data manipulation/fetch, I guess it's your layout that takes time to render. You should look into your layout files and optimize layouts by using less number of containers.

Comment: it could be, i guess i will try splash screen then , thanks a lot Anshuman

Answer (score -1):

You should have a look in [Asyntask](https://developer.android.com/samples/DisplayingBitmaps/src/com.example.android.displayingbitmaps/util/AsyncTask.html). It helps you to load/do the task that take sometime, by executing it in background thread. That would help your Activity(UI) won't be jerky.

Comment: gotta do some research about this Asyntask , as i mentioned i'm a beginner ..so XD thanks a lot man